# Error when sending blob of binary data to dynamodb

Tags: json, go, amazon-dynamodb, gob

I'm running into an issue with attempting to manage a dynamodb instance using godynamo.

My code is meant to take a gob encoded byte array and put it into dynamodb.

```
func (c *checkPointManager) CommitGraph(pop *Population) {
    var blob, err = pop.GobEncodeColorGraphs()
    fitness := pop.GetTotalFitness()
    if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
    }

    put1 := put.NewPutItem()
    put1.TableName = "CheckPoint"
    put1.Item["fitnessScore"] = &attributevalue.AttributeValue{N: string(fitness)}
    put1.Item["population"] = &attributevalue.AttributeValue{N: string(1)}
    put1.Item["graph"] = &attributevalue.AttributeValue{B: string(blob)}
    body, code, err := put1.EndpointReq()
    if err != nil || code != http.StatusOK {
            log.Fatalf("put failed %d %v %s\n", code, err, body)
    }
    fmt.Printf("values checkpointed:  %d\n %v\n %s\n", code, err, body)
```

}

Every time I run this code though, I get the following error.
     can not be converted to a Blob: Base64 encoded length is expected a multiple of 4 bytes but found: 25

Does godynamo not handle making sure a binary array specifically converts to base64? Is there an easy way for me to handle this issue?

Answer (score 0):

"Client applications must encode binary values in base64 format" according to the binary data type description of [Amazon DynamoDB Data Types](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DataModel.html#DataModel.DataTypes).

Your code could encode the value if you want, see golang's base64 package:
https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/base64

The godynamo library provides functions that will encode it for you, have a look at [AttributeValue](https://github.com/smugmug/godynamo/blob/5dbd3b0146cd832f25d80fdb8a04e174c83ff74e/types/attributevalue/attributevalue.go):

```
    // InsertB_unencoded adds a new plain string to the B field.
    // The argument is assumed to be plaintext and will be base64 encoded.
    func (a *AttributeValue) InsertB_unencoded(k string) error {
```